# italicize text of a particular row in a group of a matrix in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a SSRS 2008 report.I have created a matrix.I want to make one of the rows text to be italic based on condition in row group.I tried with below expression in font style of row group.
iif((Fields!Client.Value)="abc" ,"Italics","Default").But it is applying to all the rows in that group.
Can anyone help me how to italicize text of a particular row in a group .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried the following successfully in SSRS2005 - so think that it should also work for you.

In Fontstyle, for the row group, put

```
=IIF(Fields!Client.Value = "abc", "Italic", "Normal")
```

I tried different values in one of my reports (Using a different field) but successfully italicised the text of a single row.