# Bold the particular text in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have one column in my stored proc which contains following data:

> abcs,defs,CA(5,6);wsdf,kdh,CA(7,8)

Now I want only data in brackets to be bold and else everything regular, like so:

> abcs,defs,CA(**5,6**);wsdf,kdh,CA(**7,8**)

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473106/how-to-bring-partial-text-bold-in-a-textbox

Comment: But I want to do this in SSRS not in ASP.net and the (5,6) and (7,8) is dynamic.

Comment: Share your research with us, tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far (and see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/162730) for more in-depth info on writing questions that will give you the best answers).

Comment: Covers italics, but it should work for bold (assuming something similar exists in SSRS 2008).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703755/italicize-text-of-a-particular-row-in-a-group-of-a-matrix-in-ssrs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a custom code function to bold the text: right-click on a non-design part of the report surface, choose `Report Properties...` and click the `Code` tab. Enter the following code:

```
Function BoldText(Text As String) As String
  return Text.Replace("(", "(<b>").Replace(")", "</b>)")
End Function
```

Go to your field cell and change the expression for the value from just the field value to calling this function with the field value:

```
=Code.BoldText(Fields!FieldToBold.Value)
```

Now, this bit is the key - in your cell, click on where it shows `<<Expr>>` so it is highlighted then right-click it and choose `Placeholder Properties...`. On the `General` tab select the radio button to activate `HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles`.

Now anything between the brackets will be bolded.

**Update - changing the font colour**

You can also change the font's colour by using the `<font>` HTML tag (the following example makes anything between the brackets red and bold):

```
Function BoldText(Text As String) As String
  return Text.Replace("(", "(<font color=Red><b>").Replace(")", "</b></font>)")
End Function
```

Comment: Can you modify the function to also change the background color?

Comment: Yes, just use the <font> tag; answer updated with an example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to use placeholders to accomplish this.

[Here's](http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2010/10/31/using-different-formats-within-a-single-textbox-in-ssrs.html/)!  an excellent tutorial.