# Ways to highlight text in a cell of SSRS table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to highlight text in a cell of a SSRS table? Not the whole cell, only the text in the cell based on a condition. I don't need the change of font color and it should not apply to the whole row.

Comment: What do you mean by *highlight* if you don't want to change the font color and don't want to change the cell?

Comment: I don't see a way, at least not in 2008R2.

Comment: Background color of the text change to some other color. It should not fill the cell..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bold the particular text in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247372/bold-the-particular-text-in-ssrs)

Comment: @ChrisLätta Its not about making the text bold. Should highlight background of that text with some color like we do text highlighting while reading pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using HTML. Add a placeholder for your text and in the properties select "Interpret HTML tags as styles", then wrap the parts you want highlighted with something like this:

```
<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">This text is highlighted yellow.</span>
```